# Devise Signout in Rails API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, devise

I am working on rails 3.2 and using jquery mobile and handlebar for mobile application. I am trying to write logout functionality using API call.

in my lib/extras/api/users.rb
 i am trying to do logout functionality of devise.

How to write

For now i wrote like

```
resource :users do
        delete '/sign_out' do
          authenticate!
          user = User.find(params[:id]) rescue not_found
          # What to write here to signout the user 
          end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Warden (Devise uses it for authentication) to log the user out by first specifying a helper method which will give you the warden object:

```
def warden
  env['warden']
end
```

and then from the api you can access the helper and apply the following method on it in order to log out the user:

```
warden.logout
```